# ssh Over internet weird login

Tags: ssh, vnc

When I log in on ssh to my Raspberry Pi in the same network, everything works perfectly. 
But when I log in over the internet I get a weird welcome message http://puu.sh/1UOUN and I cant type any commands. Also vnc refuses the connection actively over the internet, but works fine to in the local network.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `reset` and ctl-L? Maybe you just don't see what you are typing.

Comment: i can type in it and see it, but its not send, it comes up with things like ^[[A if you press the arrow keys, and it responds to nothing

Comment: It could be a problem with your router configuration. How is the RPi connected to the internet? Can you access other machines on the network from the internet?

Comment: please correct your SSH client configuration. Linux sends LF as line ending not CR+LF. VNC uses a separate TCP connection for data transfer. When accessing from the Internet you need to tunnel this connection through you SSH tunnel (See putty configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `stty sane`, which makes your tty port settings "sane".

The output looks like what you see when you dump a Linux file on Windows. Are you using a different ssh client or client configuration on the inside vs outside networks?

You might also have some other program attached to that tty port. If you are able to type, try `` ps -ft `tty` `` and see if anything unexpected appears.

Comment: I think @Lars may have nailed it, above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your translation/keyboard settings?  At one point I was using a really odd computer to login to my home server over ssh and had to play with the Terminal > Keyboard settings in putty.  Also, make sure that under Window > Translation the computer you're using has UTF-8 set.